# Failed loading libmpg123.dll: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, module, pygame

I Am Getting This Error Using Pygame 64 bit Windows Python 3.9:

`Failed loading libmpg123.dll: The specified module could not be found.`

I have tried the following

- Restarting IDE
- Restarting Computer

This problem only happens with ".exe" extension. It works fine if using the ".py" extension. Any ideas on this?

Comment: if you convert script to `.exe` then sometime you have to manually add missing files because  program creating `.exe` may not know all needed libraries. You should find more information in Google.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of pyinstaller? It includes fixes to the pygame install hooks to ensure the correct DLLs are included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Downloaded That dll And Put It in the folder now it works like charm